# Django Default value for a custom user field is not added into the db tables

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I'm working on a project using `Python93.7` & `Django(2.2)` in which I have extended the user model to add a custom filed for the user. I have defined a default value for that field in the model but when I leave it empty on the form sibmission the default is not added into the DB.

Here's my model:
**From `models.py`:**

```
class CustomUser(User):
    team = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='NotInGroup', blank=True)
```

Here's my view:
**From `views.py`:**

```
if form.is_valid():
    print('form is valid')
    print(form.cleaned_data['team'])
    if not form.cleaned_data['team'] == '':
         form.team = form.cleaned_data['team']
     else:
         form.team = 'Default'
    print(form.team)
    user = form.save()
```

If I leave it empty for `form.team` it prints out the `Default` but not saved in DB.
Here's my form:
**From `forms.py`:**

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username', 'team', 'password1', 'password2')
```

Answer (score 1):

To extend a `User` model you have to use `AbstractUser` class, ie:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    team = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='NotInGroup', blank=True)
```

now in `settings.py` add `AUTH_USER_MODEL`:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.CustomUser'
```

Comment: not able to migrate this change, `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Auto-generated field 'user_ptr' in class 'CustomUser'`

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model